# Dynamically Add & Delete Table Row

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

Using some examples I found I've adapted some code, as shown below, that allows a user to add and delete table rows.

**Javascript Code**

```
function addRow(addimagetable) {
    var table = document.getElementById(addimagetable);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "radio";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "file";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);
}

function deleteRow(addimagetable) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(addimagetable);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var radio = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if (null != radio && true == radio.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

**HTML Table**

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('addimagetable')" /> <input type="button" value="Delete Row"
        onclick="deleteRow('addimagetable')" />
    <table id="addimagetable" width="407" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="20"><input type="radio" name="radio" /></td>
            <td width="147"><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
            <td width="218"><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see from the table code above, the rows are either added or deleted via a button 'click'. What I've been trying to work out is how to get rid of the 'Add' button, instead replacing it with a function whereby if a row has data in cells '2' and '3' a new row below is created.

I've been working on this for a while now and I just can't seem to find a way to get this to work.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps give me a helping hand and show me where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: **Always search in stackoverflow, there are many solutions...**  When I searched for `Add Delete Table Row [html]`, I got this... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Add+Delete+Table+Row+[html]&submit=search... Check this link...

Comment: Hi, yes you're right and it was the first thing I did before posting my question but unfortunately I couldn't find an answer to help me out with the particular problem I have. Kind regards

Comment: use the logic that is there... what is NOT working in your code then?? please explain that

Comment: Hi, I'm not particularly well versed with jQuery, but it's something that I can look into. Many thanks

Comment: @FahimParkar, many thanks for helping me out with this. What I'm unable to find is an example whereby there isn't a 'Add' button to insert a new row, instead using the completion of the row above to 'Add' the new row.

Answer (score 0):

*I found your question as I was trying to sort out a similar issue. I used your case (as it was simpler than mine) to troubleshoot the issue... I thought it was only fair to share the outcome with you.*

The following code checks every time one of your two monitored inputs in each row loses focus - if both monitored inputs for the row have values (and the row has not caused an additional row to be generated yet) then a new row is added below.

**HTML:**

```
     <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('addimagetable')" /> 
     <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('addimagetable')" /> 
     <table id="addimagetable" width="407" border="1"> 
       <tr>
           <td width="20"><input type="radio" name="radio"/></td>
           <td width="147"><input type="text" name="title" onblur="check(1)" /></td>
           <td width="218"><input type="file" name="image" onblur="check(1)" /></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
var numrows = 1; // because you are starting with 1 row visible
var rowsarray = ["0", "0"];
function addRow(addimagetable) { 
    numrows = numrows + 1;
    rowsarray[numrows] = "0";
    var table = document.getElementById(addimagetable); 
    var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
    element1.type = "radio"; 
    cell1.appendChild(element1); 
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
    var element2 = document.createElement("input"); 
    element2.type = "text"; 
    cell2.appendChild(element2); 
    element2 = cell2.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    element2.setAttribute("onblur","check("+numrows+")");
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); 
    var element3 = document.createElement("input"); 
    element3.type = "file"; 
    cell3.appendChild(element3); 
    element3 = cell3.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    element3.setAttribute("onblur","check("+numrows+")");
    } 
    function deleteRow(addimagetable) { 
    try { 
    var table = document.getElementById(addimagetable); 
    var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) { 
    var row = table.rows[i]; 
    var radio = row.cells[0].childNodes[0]; 
    if(null != radio && true == radio.checked) { 
    table.deleteRow(i); 
    rowCount--; 
    i--; 
    } 
    } 
    }catch(e) { 
    alert(e); 
    } 


} 
       function check(num) {
            table = document.getElementById('addimagetable');
            row = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[num-1];
            c1 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
            c2 = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
            if ((c1 !== "") && (c1 !== null ) && (c2 !== "") && (c2 !== null) && (rowsarray[num] !== 1)) { addRow('addimagetable'); rowsarray[num] = 1; }
        }
        </script>
```